# How to control left and right handed layout placement in an Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

I have a left handed and right handed layout which need to be placed in the appropriate column in a RecyclerView. I'm using a StaggeredGridLayout as the layouts can be of different sizes as well. I'm trying to control the placement of the child layouts and not having much luck as once the left/right orientation breaks it stays broken.

[How the layout is breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqe98.png)

The GridLayoutManager was better at keeping the layouts in order but created odd spacing when the larger layouts were used. Even if I could use the GridLayoutManager I would still need the ability to control the left/right sides as the data can arrive in a variety of orders.

I should also note that this RecyclerView is already inside of another RecyclerView so the adapter and layoutManager are being set inside of the onBindViewHolder() of the parent RV.

Comment: Please post some code so we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving this by using the GridLayoutManager options I added GridLayout in the xml.

```
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:columnCount="2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_panel">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/left_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/grid_container" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/right_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/grid_container" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Then I split the parent ArrayList into a right and left ArrayList in the OnBindViewHolder(). I end up with two child RecyclerViews, but it works and
I have fine control over the appearance.

```
        ArrayList<Breaker> leftList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Breaker> rightList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < p.getCount(); i++) {
            if (p.getB(i).getType() % 2 == 0) {
                leftList.add(p.getB(i));
            } else {
                rightList.add(p.getB(i));
            }
        }

        LinearLayoutManager leftLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(h.leftBView.getContext());
        h.leftBView.setLayoutManager(leftLayout);
        MultiAdapter leftBAdapter = new MultiBAdapter(leftList,
                h.leftBView.getContext());
        h.leftBView.setAdapter(leftBAdapter);


        LinearLayoutManager rightLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(h.rightBView.getContext());
        h.rightBView.setLayoutManager(rightLayout);
        MultiBAdapter rightBAdapter = new MultiBAdapter(rightList,
                h.rightBView.getContext());
        h.rightBView.setAdapter(rightBAdapter);
```